# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper::setDumpHeader() must be of the type string, null given

Tags: php, composer-php

After the "compoeser update", I'm getting this error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper::setDumpHeader() must be of the type string, 
null given, 
called in /home/vagrant/code/aggregation/vendor/maximebf/debugbar/src/DebugBar/DataFormatter/DebugBarVarDumper.php 
on line 288
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Please share more details. What did you update? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in the library you should downgrade the package until is fixed. For now: add to your composer.json file: "symfony/var-dumper":"<5.3.4", to force a downgrade and run composer update

https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar/issues/474

Answer (score 1):

in a composer.json add an old var-dumper

```
"require": {
...
"symfony/var-dumper": "v5.2.11",
...
```

and run

```
$ composer update
```